# Python API call to Coindesk returns 403 or 405. How do I troubleshoot?

Tags: python, nginx, urllib

I'm trying to pull json data from coindesk's API, and both methods I tried (a straight urllib.request, and then one where I passed UA data.
Both blocked me (errors below each of the code, with command line output).

Is there a way to make the code more robust? More resistant to getting blocked? As far as I can find, there is no documentation, and there is no repo I can look at, to see how their API conforms. However, I know that I am directly accessing an API that coindesk *wants* people to use, so I find this to be a bit strange (as opposed to a situation where you're scraping web data).

Thanks for your help.

This code threw a 403, and exited with the error:

**urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**

```
import urllib.request
import json
req = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
readdata = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
json_data = readdata.read()
print json_data
```

This code threw a 405 with an error of:

**urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: nginx/1.12.1**

```
import json
import urllib.request

exchange_url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
user_agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; X64)'
values = {'name' : 'Mischa Kolding',
    'location' : 'Los Angeles',
    'language' : 'Python' }
headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(exchange_url, data, headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_json = response.read()
print(the_json)
```

I should point out that navigating directly to the json link displays json in the browser.

Here is the API page for coindesk: https://www.coindesk.com/api/

EDIT:

Thanks to t.m.adam, I figured out the problem. I was doing everything but adding headers, which is all that is really needed. Thanks for helping with my noob issue:

```
#This is the API for BTC price request.  
import json
import urllib.request

url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
readdata = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
json_data = readdata.read()
print(json_data)
```

Comment: Their api seems to support only GET requests. Also were did you get those `values` from?

Comment: I sniped the form out of python documentation, and added fake values that conformed to the example.

Comment: I couldn't find any example that accepts post parameters in the api docs you linked. But your first code snippet works fine if you include a user-agent in the headers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've got it. I'll update the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown above, this code works. Header details were missing (as plain as the nose on my face).

```
#This is the API for BTC price request.  
import json
import urllib.request

url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json'
hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }

req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=hdr)
readdata = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
json_data = readdata.read()
print(json_data)
```